# Read and run lammps water model in ASE

Tags: molecular-dynamics, python, lammps, atomic-simulation-environment

I want to read a lammps data file in ASE, for instance the [TIP3P](https://docs.lammps.org/Howto_tip3p.html) or the [SPC](https://docs.lammps.org/Howto_spc.html) model. The lammps examples provide the input script and the data file, which work perfectly.

ASE is not able to read the `.mol` file: it cannot parse neither `Shake ***` nor `Shake ***` section of the lammps-data files. Thus I removed them, but even then `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mol_id_in' referenced before assignment`. Finally I wrote my own file, which can be read - see it at the bottom.

Once the file is read, I set and apply a `LammpsLib` calculator with exactly the same inputs as in the Lammps tutorial, and I receive a `Exception: ERROR: Boundary command after simulation box is defined (src/input.cpp:1414)`.

I think that the parsing messes up the order of information.

**Question: How can I see what is the input file that is fed to lammps?**

```
# Read file

import ase.io
from ase.calculators.lammpslib import LAMMPSlib

water = ase.io.read('water.mol', format='lammps-data')

lammps_orig_header = [
    'units real',
    'atom_style full',
    'region box block -5 5 -5 5 -5 5',
    'create_box 2 box  bond/types 1 angle/types 1 extra/bond/per/atom 2 extra/angle/per/atom 1 extra/special/per/atom 2'
    ]

lammps_orig_commands = [
    'mass 1 15.9994',
    'mass 2 1.008',
    
    'pair_style lj/cut/coul/cut 10.0',
    'pair_coeff 1 1 0.1553 3.166',
    'pair_coeff 1 2 0.0    1.0',
    'pair_coeff 2 2 0.0    1.0',
    
    'bond_style zero',
    'bond_coeff 1 1.0',
    
    'angle_style zero',
    'angle_coeff 1 109.47',
    
    'molecule water spce.mol',
    'create_atoms 0 random 33 34564 NULL mol water 25367 overlap 1.33',
    
    'timestep 1.0',
    'fix rigid     all shake 0.0001 10 10000 b 1 a 1',
    'minimize 0.0 0.0 1000 10000',
    'velocity all create 300.0 5463576',
    'fix integrate all nvt temp 300.0 300.0 100.0',
    
    'thermo_style custom step temp press etotal density pe ke',
    'thermo 1000',
    'run 20000 upto',
    'write_data spce.data nocoeff'
    ]

lammps = LAMMPSlib( lammps_header=lammps_orig_header,lmpcmds=lammps_orig_commands,log_file='test.log')

# Set calculator and calculate energy
water.set_calculator(lammps)
water.get_potential_energy()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 49
     47 # Set calculator and calculate energy
     48 water.set_calculator(lammps)
---> 49 water.get_potential_energy()

File ~/WORK/external_packages/ase/ase/atoms.py:737, in Atoms.get_potential_energy(self, force_consistent, apply_constraint)
    734     energy = self._calc.get_potential_energy(
    735         self, force_consistent=force_consistent)
    736 else:
--> 737     energy = self._calc.get_potential_energy(self)
    738 if apply_constraint:
    739     for constraint in self.constraints:

File ~/WORK/external_packages/ase/ase/calculators/abc.py:24, in GetPropertiesMixin.get_potential_energy(self, atoms, force_consistent)
     22 else:
     23     name = 'energy'
---> 24 return self.get_property(name, atoms)

File ~/WORK/external_packages/ase/ase/calculators/calculator.py:537, in BaseCalculator.get_property(self, name, atoms, allow_calculation)
    534     if self.use_cache:
    535         self.atoms = atoms.copy()
--> 537     self.calculate(atoms, [name], system_changes)
    539 if name not in self.results:
    540     # For some reason the calculator was not able to do what we want,
    541     # and that is OK.
    542     raise PropertyNotImplementedError(
    543         '{} not present in this ' 'calculation'.format(name)
    544     )

File ~/WORK/external_packages/ase/ase/calculators/lammpslib.py:360, in LAMMPSlib.calculate(self, atoms, properties, system_changes)
    359 def calculate(self, atoms, properties, system_changes):
--> 360     self.propagate(atoms, properties, system_changes, 0)

File ~/WORK/external_packages/ase/ase/calculators/lammpslib.py:381, in LAMMPSlib.propagate(self, atoms, properties, system_changes, n_steps, dt, dt_not_real_time, velocity_field)
    379     self.start_lammps()
    380 if not self.initialized:
--> 381     self.initialise_lammps(atoms)
    382 else:  # still need to reset cell
    383     # NOTE: The whole point of ``post_changebox_cmds`` is that they're
    384     # executed after any call to LAMMPS' change_box command.  Here, we
   (...)
    391     # apply any shrink-wrapping *after* it's updated the cell
    392     # dimensions
    393     if 'pbc' in system_changes:

File ~/WORK/external_packages/ase/ase/calculators/lammpslib.py:668, in LAMMPSlib.initialise_lammps(self, atoms)
    666             break
    667     else:
--> 668         self.lmp.command('boundary ' + self.lammpsbc(atoms))
    670 # Initialize cell
    671 self.set_cell(atoms, change=not self.parameters.create_box)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pgel/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lammps/core.py:617, in lammps.command(self, cmd)
    614 if cmd: cmd = cmd.encode()
    615 else: return
--> 617 with ExceptionCheck(self):
    618   self.lib.lammps_command(self.lmp,cmd)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pgel/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lammps/core.py:49, in ExceptionCheck.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
     47 def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
     48   if self.lmp.has_exceptions and self.lmp.lib.lammps_has_error(self.lmp.lmp):
---> 49     raise self.lmp._lammps_exception

Exception: ERROR: Boundary command after simulation box is defined (src/input.cpp:1414)
```

```
# Water molecule. TIP3P geometry

3 atoms
2 bonds
1 angles

Coords

1    0.00000  -0.06556   0.00000
2    0.75695   0.52032   0.00000
3   -0.75695   0.52032   0.00000

Types

1        1   # O
2        2   # H
3        2   # H

Charges

1       -0.834
2        0.417
3        0.417

Bonds

1   1      1      2
2   1      1      3

Angles

1   1      2      1      3
```

Comment: +1 for a well described question. It feels great to see a question with relevant details such as error codes, sample files.